# Images not loading in Flutter web release

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter web app that has some images from the network in it.
when I run it in debug mode things are fine
but when I do

```
flutter run --release
```

the images wont be loaded.

this is the part where it loads images

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  child: CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: url,
    placeholder: (context, url) => AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: post.pinimages!.first.accept_ratio!,
      child: Container(
        color:
            getColorFromHex(colorList[_random.nextInt(colorList.length)]),
      ),
    ),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Is this for Android? If so check you have internet permissions in your manifest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955789/flutter-image-network-not-working-on-release-apk?rq=2

Comment: Have you looked at this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878346/flutter-web-asset-images-not-displaying-when-deployed-to-web-server

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbitno this is for web

Comment: @ColinLazarini it is not helpful since I ask about network images not assets